# Uncertainty principle and support of functions

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be two closed ball with positive radius in $\mathbb{R}^d$. We know that if $\hat{f}$ is supported in $B_1$ then f cannot be supported in $B_2$.

Do we have furthermore that there exists $C>0$ (only depending on $B_1$ and $B_2$)

$\underset{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d), \|f\|_2=1,\, \text{supp} \hat{f}\subset B_1}{\inf} \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R^d}\setminus B_2)}\geq C$

The result might also hold for more general sets.

Comment: Check out the theorem of Amrein–Berthier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Benedicks's_theorem.